# How to tell PostgreSQL via JDBC that I'm not going to fetch every row of the query result (i.e. how to stream the head of a result set efficiently)?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, jooq

Quite frequently, I'd like to retrieve only the first `N` rows from a query, but I don't know in advance what `N` will be. For example:

```java
try(var stream = sql.selectFrom(JOB)
                    .where(JOB.EXECUTE_AFTER.le(clock.instant()))
                    .orderBy(JOB.PRIORITY.asc())
                    .forUpdate()
                    .skipLocked()
                    .fetchSize(100)
                    .fetchLazy()) {
    // Now run as many jobs as we can in 10s
    ...
}
```

Now, without adding an arbitrary LIMIT clause, the PG query planner sometimes decides to do a painfully slow *sequential table scan* for such queries, AFAIK because it thinks I'm going to fetch every row in the result set. An arbitrary LIMIT kind of works for simple cases like this one, but I don't like it at all because:

1. the limit's only there to "trick" the query planner into doing the right thing, it's not there because my intent is to fetch at most `N` rows.
2. when it gets a little more sophisticated and you have multiple such queries that  somehow depend on each other, choosing an `N` large enough to not break your code can be hard. You don't want to be the next person who has to understand that code.
3. finding out that the query is unexpectedly slow usually happens in production where your tables contain a few million/billion rows. Totally avoidable if only the DB didn't insist on being smarter than the developer.
4. I'm getting tired of writing detailed comments that explain why the queries have to look like this-n-that (i.e. explain *why* the query planner screws up if I don't add this arbitrary limit)

So, how do I tell the query planner that I'm only going to fetch a few rows and getting the first row quickly is the priority here? Can this be achieved using the JDBC API/driver?

(Note: I'm not looking for server configuration tweaks that indirectly influence the query planner, like tinkering with random page costs, nor can I accept a workaround like `set seq_scan=off`)

(Note 2: I'm using jOOQ in the example code for clarity, but under the hood this is just another `PreparedStatement` using `ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` and `ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY`, so AFAIK we can rule out wrong statement modes)

(Note 3: I'm not in autocommit mode)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PostgreSQL is smarter than you think. All you need to do is to set the fetch size of the `java.sql.Statement` to a value different from 0 using the `setFetchSize` method.  Then the JDBC driver will create a cursor and fetch the result set in chunks. Any query planned that way will be optimized for fast fetching of the first 10% of the data (this is governed by the PostgreSQL parameter `cursor_tuple_fraction`). Even if the query performs a sequential scan of a table, not all the rows have to be read: reading will stop as soon as no more result rows are fetched.

I have no idea how to use JDBC methods with your ORM, but there should be a way.

Comment: Since I am already setting a fetch size (see code example), this means I'm doomed. To sum up the situation:

Query with LIMIT, 100 rows retched: Index is used, query completes in milliseconds.
Same query without LIMIT, 100 rows fetched: Seq scan, query completes in > 10 seconds (might be much longer but already way too slow).

I don't want to call such a system smart(er than I think), and I'd surely be spending less time with it and more time on actual business problems if the system didn't try to be smart ;-)

Comment: I'll check whether setting `cursor_tuple_fraction` to (almost) zero makes a difference. I cannot expect OPS to change the parameter for the whole cluster, though.

Comment: Yes, that should make a difference: with the `LIMIT`, PostgreSQL plans for 100 result rows. Without, it plans for a tenth of the whole result set, which is probably much more.

Answer (score 1):

In case the JDBC `fetchSize()` method doesn't suffice as a hint to get the behaviour you want, you could make use of explicit server side cursors like this:

```java
ctx.transaction(c -> {
    c.dsl().execute("declare c cursor for {0}", dsl
        .selectFrom(JOB)
        .where(JOB.EXECUTE_AFTER.le(clock.instant()))
        .orderBy(JOB.PRIORITY.asc())
        .forUpdate()
        .skipLocked()
    );

    try {
        JobRecord r;

        while ((r = dsl.resultQuery("fetch forward 1 from c")
                       .coerce(JOB)
                       .fetchOne()) != null) {
            System.out.println(r);
        }
    }
    finally {
        c.dsl().execute("close c");
    }
});
```

There's a pending feature request to support the above also in the DSL API (see [#11407](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11407)), but the above example shows that this can still be done in a type safe way using [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) and the [`ResultQuery::coerce`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#coerce(org.jooq.Table)) method

Comment: I'll try this and report back whether it makes a difference. I'd be somewhat surprised though, since @Laurenz Albe's answer suggests that a server-side cursor (and therefore the effect of `cursor_tuple_fraction` on query plans) is already being used whenever a fetch size is set.

Comment: @daniel-huss: I'd be surprised too, though, you already set the fetch size in your question, so I assumed it wasn't working. Looking through pgjdbc source code, I couldn't find anything obvious that would trigger such cursor usage, though maybe I overlooked some side-effect of the internal flags that are being passed around... In any case, it's interesting to see that these cursors can be used explicitly, with jOOQ (with one server roundtrip per fetch, of course)

Comment: @daniel-huss: Note, if you do find a significant difference, you could try removing jOOQ from the equation and reporting an issue to https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc

Comment: While it's neat that you can do this with jOOQ, it didn't have an effect on the query plan, so I guess setting `cursor_tuple_fraction` to a very low value is the way to go. Luckily the parameter can be changed for just the current session/java.sql.Connection.